# Network check works in android but same doesn't work in iOS

Tags: codenameone

I checked NetworkManager.getInstance().getCurrentAccessPoint() equals to null or not to determine if there is a network connection or not. It's simple & works great in android but in iOS, it always shows false. How can i make it work in iOS. Before I had used a cn1 library for this purpose. I think its by steve but using the library, I felt it makes the app a bit slower. So i used the code below.

```
public static boolean check_online() {
    boolean online = false;
    String net = NetworkManager.getInstance().getCurrentAccessPoint();
    if (net == null || "".equals(net) || net.equals(null)) {
        online = false;
    } else {
        online = true;
    }
    return online;
}

@Override
protected void postExample(Form f) {
    if (check_online()) {
        ecc = new CategoryConnection();
        ecc.egCategoryConnectionMethod(this);
        - - - - - -- - 
        //codes
        - - - - - -- -
    }
}else {
        noConnection = new Label("No connection");
        f.add(noConnection);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is implemented only for Android/RIM as it's very device specific. iOS doesn't provide access point control.

There is a cn1lib in the extensions section that allows you to detect if there is a network connection or isn't which I guess is what you are really looking for.

Comment: thankyou shai. I have tried using connectivity library. https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/codenameone-connectivity but it displays white blank screen for a couple of seconds in all the screens. So it feels like a bit slower and odd. Is this the library you mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, but it's not supposed to show anything. You can call it from a separate thread if it causes a delay for the EDT.